# What is the best multi frozen column + rows table/grid component in React?

Tags: reactjs, datagrid, html-table

What is the currently best React Grid / Table Component supporting both - multifrozen columns + multifrozen header rows together ?

There are tons of components which support multiple frozen columns but without option to freeze header or components which support one frozen header row (I need more than just one) but do not have option to freeze columns.

Any golden mean here?

Comment: Can't assume what frozen header row means, but there is a fixed header meaning, may be this ReactJS table plug-in will be helpful - https://github.com/GigaTables/reactables